# Renaming column/variable values (in certain rows)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following table (in reality many more rows):

```
country         sessions     rank    
United Kingdom   100846        1    
Spain             80628        2    
Italy              7628        3    
USA                6628        4     
France             1328        5     
China              1228        6     
Japan              1128        7     
Russia             1028        8     
Japan               928        9     
Greece              828        10
Colombia            728        11     
Brasil              628        12     
Portugal             28        13
```

I would like to rename countries `France`, `China`, `Japan`, `Russia`, ... and `Portugal` as `Other`.
Is there any way of renaming those countries by condition such as row number or rank or session? 
Thank you

Comment: `df$country <- gsub("Portugal|France|China|Japan|Russia", "Other", df$country)`

Comment: I have like 50 countries more after Portugal which I would also like to rename as Other

Comment: What is the criteria to rename them?

Comment: At some point you are going to have to type them all out.

Comment: Criteria: sessions less than 1300 = "Other"

Comment: So why France then?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
df$country <- ifelse(df$session < 1300, "Other", df$country)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some.table %>%
  mutate(country = ifelse(rank <= 4, country, "Other"))
```

Comment: Thanks to all! Beutiful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming country is a factor variable, in base R, you can use `levels<-` together with subsetting `[` twice to obtain this goal.

Using the criteria that session < 1300,

```
levels(dat$country)[dat$country][dat$sessions < 1300] <- "Other"
```

Using the criteria that rank > 5

```
levels(dat$country)[dat$country][dat$rank > 5] <- "Other"
```

The first `[`, `[dat$country]`, reorders the levels to fit the order of the data.frame, and the second performs the subsetting based on the desired criterion.

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(country = structure(c(11L, 10L, 6L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 
7L, 9L, 7L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 8L), .Label = c("Brasil", "China", "Colombia", 
"France", "Greece", "Italy", "Japan", "Portugal", "Russia", "Spain", 
"United Kingdom", "USA"), class = "factor"), sessions = c(100846L, 
80628L, 7628L, 6628L, 1328L, 1228L, 1128L, 1028L, 928L, 828L, 
728L, 628L, 28L), rank = 1:13), .Names = c("country", "sessions", 
"rank"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```